# Detecting buggy GLSL implementations on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl

I am having trouble with my vertex shader. In outputs skewed images as shown.

On my Galaxy S (2.3.6/Gingerbread) it is skewed. On my mother's Iconia, it works perfectly. I need to be able to detect buggy implementatations. I'm thinking of rendering this image to a buffer and checking that is renders properly. I think the best way to detect?

I have coloured that vertices so that red=x, green=y and blue=z converting from range [-1, 1] to [0, 1]. This is so that I can see where the vertices have been transformed from.
 [image: Vertex Shader Image]

Next is an image of the same item rendered using OpenGLES 1.0. This one has the texture applied as it would take more effort to colour it like the first image. As you can see, is looks correct.
[image]

Comment: What version of Android is on the Iconia?

Comment: I think it's a little premature to call an entire glsl implementation faulty just because your cube doesn't come out like you expect. Are you checking for `glGetError`s? What does your code look like?

Comment: @Tim: True, buggy is probably closer. I tried all sorts of different configurations and compared the images and I can't see how the GS arrived at that image. I've been working on it for a whole week and the exact same code works on the newer one and not the older.
All of the glGetError calls after every line come up clean. That's why I tested with as many values defined directly in GLSL as possible to test the outcome.
The Galaxy S Originally came with 2.1, which doesn't support OPENGLES2 so maybe that has something to do with it.

Comment: Can't see why this has been voted down, it's a perfectly legitimate question.
One implementation works correctly, one doesn't.

Comment: @Ben: It's been downvoted because you didn't give us anything to go on besides "it doesn't work." There is absolutely no way you could expect anyone to be able to help you unless they just so happened to run into the exact same problem. At the *very least*, you should have posted your vertex shader.

Comment: @Nicol: Thanks. Yes, I just realised that. I thought I had posted it but obviously not. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here's how I solved it:

I created the function

```
mat4 mmult(mat4 a, mat4 b){
    return a*b;
}
```

Then changed:

```
current *= animMatrix;
```

to:

```
current = mmult(current, animMatrix);
```

And it worked.

Tried this too:

```
current = current * animMatrix;
```

But it also returned the wrong image.

I have no logical explanation for this, but it seems to be the fix.
Any comments on why would be greatly appreciated.